# Stop timer after some time in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I wanted to perform some operation repeatedly in 200ms interval , starting from time t=0 to t=10 sec.

Currently I am keeping track of elapsed time in a variable. This looks uncomfortable to me. Below is the code-

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

class Program
{
    static int interval = 200; // 0.2 seconds or 200 ms
    static int totalTime = 10000; // 10 seconds or 10000 ms
    static int elapsedTime = 0; // Elapsed time in ms

    static Timer timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new Timer(interval);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        timer.Enabled = true;

        Console.ReadKey(); // for checking
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (elapsedTime > totalTime)
            timer.Stop();

        else
        {
            // here I am performing the task, which starts at t=0 sec to t=10 sec
        }
        elapsedTime += interval;
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest, if there exist any better way to perform the same task. Sample code is always appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stop the timer in your event and start again, just to make sure that your execution doesn't enter the event twice.  Like:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    if (elapsedTime > totalTime)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // here I am performing the task, which starts at t=0 sec to t=10 sec
        timer.Enabled = true; //Or timer.Start();
    }
    elapsedTime += interval;
}
```

Comment: if the machine is very slow and the interval is very small there is a chance that a new event could be fired before the Stop method is processed. Will probably never happen, but the only guarantee is to try to obtain a lock and exit if it cannot be acquired

Comment: @NewHire: What if my task (which is being performed inside else block) takes let say 100ms to execute. In this case the actual elapsed time would be 200ms+100ms, which is not considered here :(

What do you feel about it? As said earlier, I want to execute this in 200ms delay repeatedly starting from 0 till 10 seconds.

Comment: @RaviJoshi, No. Your elapsed time would be 200ms, since your task would only take 100ms, and the timer would wait for the remaining 100 ms before firing again.